# Having trouble removing first and last character from urls in csv

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am getting the following error when using `requests` `requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for`'['https://www.example.com/contact/find..']' . So there are these two braces at the start and at the end of the links which I am reading from a csv file. These braces end up there because of this statement `links_total.append('https://www.example.com'+cell_link['href'])` . I am trying to slice the row before `requests` .Is not working. I used `row = row[1:-1]` which gives the following error `requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: []`. I'd like to remove these braces.

```
try:
    with open('rt.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
      csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
      for row in csv_reader:
        row = row[1:-1]
        page2 = requests.get(row)
```

This line is from a program I used to scrape these links to the csv file. `links_total.append('https://www.example.com'+cell_link['href'])`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `re` module, check the `re` module [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with `row = row[-1]` and it worked.